# How to start debugging this error in an Ember app

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools

I adopted this Ember app and started getting this error. Is there any good tools to help me figure out what is undefined other than caveman debugging?

[image]

Comment: How about click on one of those VM3953* links and see what's happening? Do you have access to unminimized sources?

Comment: Please post the code where you have used Ember.Object. Code helps debug!

Comment: thx, will dig through this more; yes I do have access to unminified code